# Gradle 6.5 AS 4.1 Setting outputFileName got The value for this property cannot be changed any further error

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have a gradle task that is called when I do release apk, I call it in this way:

```
tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name == 'preDeployBuild') {
        task.dependsOn deployTask
    }
}
```

Task it self is:

```
task deployTask {
    doFirst {
        versionCode = versionJSON.buildNumber
        latestVersionCode = versionCode
        println "$versionCode"
        versionFile.write(new JsonBuilder(versionJSON).toPrettyString())
        def versionNameRelease = getVersionNameRelease()
        ext.latestVersionName = versionNameRelease
        android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.all {
                println "$versionNameRelease"
                println "$versionCode"
                versionNameOverride = versionNameRelease
                versionCodeOverride = versionCode
                outputFileName = "${appName}_${latestVersionName}.${new Date().format('yyyyMMdd')}.apk"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I updated to Gradle 6.5 and this not work any more, got this error:

```
> The value for this property cannot be changed any further.
```

Which is the correct way to update versioName versionCode and outputFileName during gradle task running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved in this way

Make task a function and call inside buildTypes block:

```
    releaseMajor {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            def startTask =  project.gradle.startParameter.taskNames[0]
            if(startTask == ':app:assembleReleaseMajor') {
                increaseMajor()
                relaseTask()
            }
        }
```

and in function relaseTask do stuff:

```
def relaseTask() {
....
    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.all {
            println "$versionNameRelease"
            println "$versionCode"
            versionNameOverride = versionNameRelease
            versionCodeOverride = versionCode
            outputFileName = "${appName}_${latestVersionName}.${new Date().format('yyyyMMdd')}.apk"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have the same issue

```
      def fileNameCreate = { variant ->
            variant.outputs.all { output ->
                outputFileName = "epromo-${variant.versionName}(${variant.versionCode})-${variant.baseName}.apk"
            }
        }
```

outputFileName  - Gradle error: The value for this property cannot be changed any further.

Answer (score 0):

This error is throwing by :

```
org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractProperty$FinalizedValue.java#beforeMutate(String)

@Override
public void beforeMutate(DisplayName displayName) {
     throw new IllegalStateException(String.format("The value for %s is final and cannot be changed any further.", displayName.getDisplayName()));
}
```

And **outputFileName** is a class of **org.gradle.api.internal.provider.DefaultProperty**(extends AbstractProperty)

outputFileName:property(java.lang.String, fixed(class java.lang.String, app-xx-armeabi-v7a-debug.apk))
outputFileName:class org.gradle.api.internal.provider.DefaultProperty
state:org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractProperty$NonFinalizedValue@6057143f
state:class org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractProperty$**NonFinalizedValue**

outputFileName:property(java.lang.String, fixed(class java.lang.String, app-xxx-arm64-v8a-release.apk))
outputFileName:class org.gradle.api.internal.provider.DefaultProperty
state:org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractProperty$**FinalizedValue**@472cba66
state:class org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractProperty$FinalizedValue

so you can't modify  **outputFileName** in release build .

Good Luck!